# Is there any way of only retrieving posts with one or more thumbs up (GD star rating plugin)?

Tags: query-posts, plugin-gd-star-rating

I'm building a website that uses the [GD star rating plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/).

Right now, I'm using the following code to retrieve two posts of the current page (a custom post type called `bbp_topic`) and sort them by vote:

```
<?php query_posts('gdsr_sort=thumbs&posts_per_page=2&post_parent='.$post->ID); ?>
```

I would like now to only retrieve those post that have 1 or more thumbs up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gdsr_ftvmin=1` is probably the query parameter you need

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
gdsr_sort=rating&gdsr_order=desc
```

Comment: I don't think that would work since I don't want to retrieve posts that have 0 or less thumbs.